# How to read data from this XML file with PHP?

Tags: php

**Making a Connection**

```
$Game_ID            = $Game_Search->Game[$i]->id;
$Game_Info_URL      = 'http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id='.$Game_ID;
$Game_Info_Output   = simplexml_load_file($Game_Info_URL);
```

**Retrieving Data Example**

```
$Game_Info_Images = $Game_Info_Output->Game->Images;
```

For this question please refer to [this URL](http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=90) where I would like to get the Game->Images-> Box Art Side A and Side B. How do I call this?

**XML Doc (Just required Fields)**

```
<Data>
    <baseImgUrl>http://thegamesdb.net/banners/</baseImgUrl>
    <Game>
        <Images>
            <boxart side="back" width="1518" height="2148" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/back/90-1.jpg">boxart/original/back/90-1.jpg</boxart>
            <boxart side="front" width="1530" height="2148" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/front/90-1.jpg">boxart/original/front/90-1.jpg</boxart>
        </Images>
    </Game>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

**XML Doc (Just required Fields)**

```
<Data>
    <baseImgUrl>http://thegamesdb.net/banners/</baseImgUrl>
    <Game>
        <Images>
            <boxart side="back" width="1518" height="2148" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/back/90-1.jpg">boxart/original/back/90-1.jpg</boxart>
            <boxart side="front" width="1530" height="2148" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/front/90-1.jpg">boxart/original/front/90-1.jpg</boxart>
        </Images>
    </Game>
</Data>
```

To read side="front" **width="1530"**... simply use;

```
boxart["Attribute_Name"]
```

Examples:

```
Game->Images->boxart[$b]["side"] // Gets the side value front/back
Game->Images->boxart[$b]["width"] // gets the width value
Game->Images->boxart[$b]["height"] // gets the height value
Game->Images->boxart[$b]["thumb"] // gets the thumb value
```

Answer (score 0):

DomDocument and/or Xpath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=90');
$xpath      = new DOMXPath($dom);
$baseImgUrl = $xpath->query('//baseImgUrl')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$boxartBackSide  = $xpath->query('//Game/Images/boxart[@side="back"]')
    ->item(0)->nodeValue;
$boxartFrontSide = $xpath->query('//Game/Images/boxart[@side="front"]')
    ->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: I've never done DomDocument so I'll wait to see if  anyone comments on this as to me, my own answer seems simpler...